# Where's the documentation for "Enable All JSON editor features" for Visual Studio, when editing a C# file?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio

When editing a string in Visual Studio there's an option called `Enable All JSON editor features`, which adds a comment to the data.
[image: Screenshot of the Quick Actions]

The comment looks like this:

```cs
/*lang=json,strict*/
```

It pops up only if the string in C# code contains serialized JSON.
I wasn't able to find any documentation online for it. Is it some hidden feature?
Are other languages (SQL/YAML/JavaScript) supported in strings in a similar fashion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only know that `lang=regex` is also supported.

However, in .NET7 for:

- better handling of string literals and
- adding a semantic meaning to strings

please see:

1. Raw string literals:

   - No more `\"` escaping,
   - great leading spaces handling, and
   - great interpolation experience.
     From [C# 11 Preview Updates – Raw string literals, UTF-8 and more!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp-11-preview-updates/#raw-string-literals):

     > [image]
2. `StringSyntaxAttribute` which allows you to mark parameters with their meaning which then becomes a clue to the editor. For example:

   ```
   var s = "...";
   ...
   void F([StringSyntax(StringSyntaxAttribute.DateTimeFormat)]string s)
   ```

   in an editor which supports it (e.g. Visual Studio 2022) would:

   - add hints as you type `s` (hints with `yyyy`, `MM`, etc.),
   - add errors if the string doesn't make sense (in my experience this works best with `StringSyntaxAttribute.Json` for now).

     As of Jan 2023 this feature is neither finished nor documented well. The best introduction I know is [The .NET 7 feature that gives meaning to your Strings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2YOaqSAJAQ) (video, ~7mins).